# Not authorised to send Apple Events to Finder from helper bundle

Tags: macos, applescript, bundle, nsapplescript

I'm having issues with executing AppleScript from the application helper bundle, which is contained in my main application bundle.

I have a simple helper application bundle which only loads my script located in helpers' bundle Resources using NSAppleScript API and executes it. Script is really simple, it basically just deletes some other application bundle. I've tested the script as standalone and everything works fine. When I run the helper bundle everything falls apart. I'm getting -1743 error (Not authorised to send Apple Events to Finder). My helper bundle is not sandboxed, has enabled apple events in the entitlements file and I've added NSAppleEventsUsageDescription key to the plist. If I run this from Xcode it works, same if I execute the binary contained in the bundle from command line.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem by adding `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key to all `Info.plist` files up the bundle hierarchy.